# Как происходит мгновеное обновление данных в vk.com?

Tags: вконтакте

Пример:
В браузере Opera пользователь Коля изменил статус на своей странице.

В браузере IE пользователь Юля находясь на странице пользователя Коли увидела то что статус на его странице изменился.

Между теми событиями как одни пользователь изменил свой статус и тем то что другой пользователь увидел то что статус изменился проходит меньше секунды.

Вопрос как в vk.com этого добились?

Answer (score 1):

[comet](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104945/) и подобные методы.

Comment: Причём мощность их серверов и мозги оптимизаторов их кода позволяют посылать запросы к серверу и несколько раз в секунду.